# how can i round off my value based on user input?

Tags: c#, asp.net, rounding

i have this code in my updatetobill code. im planning to round it off to nearest tenth i think? for example the price is 123456.123456, what i want to do is to have it as 123456.12 because since its a price, i need the cents. thanks in advance for any help :)

```
private void UpdateTotalBill()
    {
        double vat = 0;
        double TotalPrice = 0;
        long TotalProducts = 0;
        foreach (DataListItem item in dlCartProducts.Items)
        {
            Label PriceLabel = item.FindControl("lblPrice") as Label; // get price 
            TextBox ProductQuantity = item.FindControl("txtProductQuantity") as TextBox; // get quantity
            double ProductPrice = Convert.ToInt64(PriceLabel.Text) * Convert.ToInt64(ProductQuantity.Text); //computation fro product price. price * quantity
            vat = (TotalPrice + ProductPrice) * 0.12; // computation for total price. total price + product price
            TotalPrice = TotalPrice + ProductPrice+40 +vat;
            TotalProducts = TotalProducts + Convert.ToInt32(ProductQuantity.Text);

        }
        Label1.Text = Convert.ToString(vat);
        txtTotalPrice.Text = Convert.ToString(TotalPrice); // put both total price and product values and converting them to string
        txtTotalProducts.Text = Convert.ToString(TotalProducts);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just round it [`Math.Round`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75ks3aby%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like;

```
Math.Round(TotalPrice, 2) // 123456.12
```

Also you can use [`Math.Round(Double, Int32, MidpointRounding)` overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f5898377%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to specify your `MidpointRounding` is `AwayFromZero` or `ToEven`. `ToEven` is the default option.

Comment: how can i implement the code if it is based on user input? txtTotalPrice.Text = Convert.ToString(TotalPrice);

Comment: @PaoloDuhaylungsod Just use as `Math.Round(TotalPrice, 2)`?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this when you want to transform `string` is using the `CurrencyFormat`. You can use the code below:

```
txtTotalPrice.Text = TotalPrice.ToString("C"); 
txtTotalProducts.Text = TotalProducts.ToString("C");
```

Instead which:

```
txtTotalPrice.Text = Convert.ToString(TotalPrice);
txtTotalProducts.Text = Convert.ToString(TotalProducts);
```